# How do I toggle a class on click of an element but remove the same class from all other elements using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying my best to word this properly so please bear with me. So I'm trying to only toggle a class (active) on an element that is clicked. If another element is clicked I would like to add the class "active" to the element clicked and remove the active class from any other element.

The problem is when I click on one element the "active" class is added but then when I click on another element the "active" class isn't removed from the other elements

```
           $("li.test a").click(function() {
                $(this).toggleClass("active");

            });

            $("li.test a").click(function() {
                $(this).toggleClass("active");
            });


            $("li.test a").click(function() {
                $(this).toggleClass("active");

            });
```

HTML

```
<li class="test1">
 <a href="#" class="">
</li>

<li class="test1">
 <a href="#" class="">
</li>

<li class="test1">
 <a href="#" class="">
</li>

<li class="test2">
 <a href="#" class="">
</li>

<li class="test2">
 <a href="#" class="">
</li>

<li class="test2">
 <a href="#" class="">
</li>
```

Comment: Do you realize you are adding three click events to all the elements?

Answer (score 5):

Here's the working code:

```js
$("li.test a").on("click",function() {
  if($(this).hasClass("active")){
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  } else{
    $("a.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.active{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="test">
 <a href="#" class="">test</a>
</li>

<li class="test">
 <a href="#" class="">test</a>
</li>

<li class="test">
 <a href="#" class="">test</a>
</li>

<li class="test">
 <a href="#" class="">test</a>
</li>

<li class="test">
 <a href="#" class="">test</a>
</li>

<li class="test">
 <a href="#" class="">test</a>
</li>
```

[(Working pen)](http://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/YzPjWXN)

Be aware you have classes "test1" and "test2" in the HTML, but class "test" in the JS!

Answer (score 3):

Use the `not` method to skip your current element.

```
$("li.test a").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.test a').not($this).removeClass('active');
    $this.toggleClass("active");

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the class from other elements before toggling.

Try this

```
$("li.test a").click(function() {
    $("li.test a.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

This first removes all the anchors with class active and then toggles the clicked anchor with the class.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```js
$("li").click(function(){
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
li.active a{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
<li class="test1 active">
 <a href="#" class="">test</a>
</li>

<li class="test1">
 <a href="#" class="">test</a>
</li>

<li class="test1">
 <a href="#" class="">test</a>
</li>

<li class="test2">
 <a href="#" class="">test</a>
</li>

<li class="test2">
 <a href="#" class="">test</a>
</li>

<li class="test2">
 <a href="#" class="">test</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through below mentioned link or below mentioned code may be it can help you.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p3c58eLe/6/)

HTML Code

```
<li class="test">
<a href="#" class="">test</a>
</li>
<li class="test">
  <a href="#" class="">test</a>
</li>
<li class="test">
  <a href="#" class="">test</a>
</li>
<li class="test">
  <a href="#" class="">test</a>
</li>
<li class="test">
  <a href="#" class="">test</a>
</li>
<li class="test">
  <a href="#" class="">test</a>
</li>
```

CSS Code

```
.active{
  color:#00adef;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT Code

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $('a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```